# iOS accessibility: how to label buttons that have content that can be changed by tapping them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, accessibility

Are there any official references e.g. documentation on how to enable UI controls for accessibility, where the control has content that can be altered through tapping it? One example may be a button that displays a user's email address, that allows the user to update the email address by tapping the button and filling out a new email address.

The WWDC session, "Writing Great Accessibility Labels" from 2019 did not include any information on the topic.

Comment: Maybe you can find it here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about official guidelines, but I would suggest adding the suffix "tap to edit" to the voiceover in that case.

(So something like VO = "user email address is 'JoeSmith@google.com'. Tap to edit. Button", where the system adds the "Button." bit to the VO for all buttons automatically.)